# Add elements to element that was dynamically inserted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a single page application where, by default is content for anyone to see, however, if the session of the user is admin (via forum session added by PHP) add some content so the admin can modify the page without refresh, so lots of ajax.

My idea how I can accomplish this is to load two scripts, app.js is for default behavior, and if admin, load in the admin.js file. In admin.js, I want to modify the content that was dynamically loaded in already to load in specific controls, such as buttons, forms, etc for the admin.

So, for this SPA I'm using jQuery and handlebars.js to load in the default view, where content is from an api.

app.js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api.php?type=packages"
}).done(function(res) {
    const obj = $.parseJSON(res);
    const category = 766773;
    $.each(JSON.parse(obj)['payload'], function(k, v) {
        if (v.category == category) {
            const context = {
                packageName: v.name,
                packageId: v.id
            };
            const source = $('#item-template').html();
            const template = Handlebars.compile(source);
            const html = template(context);

            $('#items').append(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Now in admin.js, so far, I'm just trying to add in what already is dynamic content:

```
function initAdminControls () {
  var editBtn = $('<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn red darken-2"><i class="material-icons">grade</i>Edit</a>');
  $('.btn-container').append(editBtn);
}

initAdminControls();
```

Not working. The function runs (tested with a `console.log`) but because of the dynamic elements, the link won't append to the `.btn-container`

I know that there is `.on()` however I'm not sure how to use it after dynamic content is loaded, and I'm not exactly adding any events (yet) so I'm not sure what my other options.

So my question is, how can I append my new `<a>` element to `.btn-container` when `.btn-container` is already being dynamically added?

Here is [the project](http://45.55.34.137/p) I'm working on: .

Comment: Try $(document).find('.btn-container')

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.btn-container', function () {
// do stuff });

Comment: It is probably a timing issue since the "done" callback is not invoked until the ajax request receives a response. The admin.js logic is probably running before the "done" callback is invoked.

Comment: I assumed so, how can I fix this? and @Gerard, I'm not running any events, I just need to add in elements once .done is, well, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be related that the function gets invoked before the content is rendered in the done callback.
What you can do, is invoke the function inside your done callback, checking if the function is correctly defined (so only when also the admin script gets included). You can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api.php?type=packages"
}).done(function(res) {
    const obj = $.parseJSON(res);
    const category = 766773;
    $.each(JSON.parse(obj)['payload'], function(k, v) {
        if (v.category == category) {
            const context = {
                packageName: v.name,
                packageId: v.id
            };
            const source = $('#item-template').html();
            const template = Handlebars.compile(source);
            const html = template(context);

            $('#items').append(html);
            if (typeof(initAdminControls) === 'function') {
                initAdminControls();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And remove the init from the main script of admin. 
In this way that section of the admin gets initialized only after the callback